# Is there any compare option available in Apache Flink streaming?

Tags: scala, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

For our use case, we would like the ability to compare the streaming data while subscribing from the AMPS Server [CRANK UP THE AMPS]. Is there a built-in function or any options to compare the previous value of the streaming execution result?

Comment: The question isn't clear. Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Flink features [stateful streaming](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/state/), and offers several solutions for detecting patterns and trends:

- You can use state in an operator like a RichFlatMap or [ProcessFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html) to remember information about previous events, and use this when processing subsequent events.
- [CEP](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/libs/cep.html) is a library that implements a DSL (executed by a finite state machine) for doing complex event processing.
- [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html) is a feature of Flink's Stream SQL that is used to detect patterns.